# Where did Asuka think "Monaka" came from?

Tags: japanese-language, hibike-euphonium

In the bonus episode, the group of players who don't make the cut to play in the competition form a B-Squad named Monaka, after the first character of their three second-year members' names.

When they announce this name to the rest of the club, Asuka misunderstands and thinks the name has something to do with youth:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> Asuka: "Monaka". We're in the thick of our youth! Or something.
>   Girl: No, we just took the start of the second-years' names.

Where did Asuka think they had gotten the name "Monaka" from?

Comment: i wouldn't be surprised if Asuka was getting it from the Kanji or it's meaning shown in the first frame since i have see stuff like that before like in Death Note in how Misa describes how Light's name is written as Moon and [this in Aoishiro](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11697/1587). though i don't know what that meaning could be since i can't read it

Comment: @Memor-X I can't read it either, but I thought it might be important so I included it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what Asuka said in Japanese:

> なるほど…最中【もなか】。私達【わたしたち】は青春【せいしゅん】真っ【まっ】最中【さいちゅう】～的【てき】な？
>
> I see... *monaka*. We're *in the middle* of our youth~ or something?

The idea is, [最中](https://www.japandict.com/%E6%9C%80%E4%B8%AD) (in the middle) is usually read as "*saichuu*", but also has another reading of "*monaka*". As for why Asuka connected it to "youth", it's a common idea that school life is related to youth life.

---

Monaka itself is actually [a wafer cake filled with the bean jam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaka). The origin of *monaka* is from 最中【もなか】の月【つき】 which has the meaning of ["the shape of full moon"](http://gogen-allguide.com/mo/monaka.html).