# Why do people think people with good knife skills are hiding things?

Tags: japanese-language, tales-of-zestiria

When I was playing *Tales of Graces f*, if Pascal and Cheria were in the party, there would be a victory scene where [Pascal would comment on Cheria's knife work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUEuQvJAlCU&t=247s) and questions if she's hiding anything else

> **Pascal:** That's some fancy knife work, what else are you hiding from us?
> **Cheria:** I'm not hiding anything!

At first I passed this off as being some in-game joke with how Cheria obviously had feelings for Asbel but tries to hide it and is being called out by Pascal who can be a bit oblivious (eg. thinking Hubert's confession of his feeling to her was him reminding her about Asbel's and Cheria's future wedding)

However while playing *Tales of Zestiria* I came across the same sort of victory scene, this time between Edna and Rose which plays out much the same with Edna taking Pascal's place and Rose taking Cheria's. I've only just passed dealing with Cardinal Forton and at this point Rose, aside from being coy when she gets intel from the Scattered Bones, has been fairly upfront especially when it comes to killing people. And in both of these cases Cheria and Rose don't seem like your typical shady thief types (the party keeps pointing out how unlike assassins the Scattered Bones are, particularly Rose)

I am wondering is this actually some sort of joke or [word pun that was lost in translation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11697/1587)? If so what is the meaning behind it?

Comment: At the language level, it means just what it says. They seem to be of the same _Tales_ series, so it may be that  the creator simply used the same phrase. [This wiki](https://w.atwiki.jp/to_graces/pages/34.html#id_51fdcfe9) annotates the Pascal's phrase with 'looking at the breast' (胸の辺りをみながら), which might imply Pascal's suggesting the (large) breast is fake.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the cliche is that someone who is really good at using a knife while cooking is hiding that he is really a Ninja or something like that.

So noticing someone being good at using a knife in battle and alluding he is hiding something, it's most likely his cooking skills.

Or it could just be a diss. "Usually you are so bad at this, but now you show some skill. What else have you been hiding?"

Here's the [Japanese version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saj4riFLHXQ&t=698s) of the scene for reference.